# filter based on a field value in awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to print the countries which which have `to` after `~:`.

```
welcome~:to~:Germany
welcome~:no please~:Italy
welcome~:to~:Brazil
welcome~:not ok~:China
```

Note: I do not know what will be there other than "`to`". It can be anything and can be changed (like `no please`, `not ok`).

I am tried using cut, awk, sed. But I am unable to figure out.

```
awk -F "~:" '{print $2 $NF}'
```

But I get output like:

```
toGermany
no pleaseItaly
toBrazil
not okChina
```

How to filter countries other than `to`.

**UPDATE:**

Alternative solution:(Figured out with cut) :-)

```
grep -v "to" |cut -d ':' -f3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are using `~:` as field separator you can check if second field is equal to `to` and to print third field which is the country:

```
awk -F"~:" '$2 == "to" { print $3; }' file
```

Result:

```
Germany
Brazil
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget `sed` solution:

```
sed -n '/~:to~:/s/.*://p'
```

or more qiuck (may be)

```
sed '/~:/{s/to~:/\n/;D}'
```